# TypeError when using urllib.request in place of urllib2

Tags: python

I am trying to convert code that was previously written for `Python 2.7` to code that will work in `Python 3.4`. The code is below and I had to change `urllib2.urlopen()` to `urllib.request.urlopen()`. However, this change resulted in the error `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'` in the line `compressedFile.write(response.read())`.

```
import os
import urllib2
import gzip
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file="
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"
outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename) #Changed this to urllib.request.urlopen()
compressedFile = StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decode the bytes before passing it to the write function

```
compressedFile = StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Also see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode). `"utf-8"` may be omitted because it's the default, but explicit is better than implicit ;-)

Comment: @TimCastlijns Thank You. However, I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`.

Comment: @user131983 try with `response.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")`. Note that while that should make it work, it will leave out the bytes it can't convert.

Comment: @TimCastlijns Thanks. But, that resulted in the error `TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: @user131983 on what line?

Comment: Sorry its in a different line of code that I haven't posted here. I'll create a new question for it as again I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Append a call to `decode()` to decode the `bytes` into a `str`.

```
compressedFile.write(response.read().decode())
```